# Can't set attribute on relationship neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm running the following cypher code. It used to work perfectly on previous versions of neo4j. Now it's not setting the attributes. The CSV file is intact and do possess the following fields. In the shell it's not even showing the line number on the last two rows, it's like it's completely ignoring the command.

```
using periodic commit
load csv with headers from "file:/relacionamento.csv" as row
match (p1:Pessoa {idpessoa: toint(row.idpessoa1)})
match (p2:Pessoa {idpessoa: toint(row.idpessoa2)})
create (p1)-[r:RELACIONAMENTO]->(p2) set r.peso_relacionamento = tofloat(row.peso_relacionamento), 
r.peso_relacionamento_ponderado = tofloat(row.peso_relacionamento_fator)
```

Comment: What version of Neo4j are you using?

Comment: 3.0.3. I had 2.8 if I'm not mistaken and it was working just fine

Comment: @YanMendes Minimal example of a both CSV files - `vértices.csv` and `relacionamento.csv` - on which replicate the problem?

Comment: @YanMendes Is the relationship r created? Is it possible that they already exist in the database prior to you running it.